# Python to javascript communication

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, encoding

OK so im using websockets to let javascript talk to python and that works very well BUT the data i need to send often has several parts like an array, (username,time,text) but how could i send it ? I originally though to encode each one in base64 or urlencode then use a character like | which those encoding methods will never use and then split the information. Unfortunately i cant find a method which both python and javascript can both do.

So the question, is there a encoding method which bath can do OR is there a different better way i can send the data because i havent really done anything like this before. (I have but AJAX requests and i send that data URL encoded). Also im not sending miles of text, about 100bytes at a time if that.
thankyou !

### edit

Most comments point to JSON,so, Whats the best convert to use for javascript because javascript stupidly cant convert string to JSON,or the other way round.

### Finished

Well jaascript does have a native way to convert javascript to string, its just hidden form the world. JSON.stringify(obj, [replacer], [space]) to convert it to a string and JSON.parse(string, [reviver]) to convert it back

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are not present in all JavaScript implementations. Many older browsers do not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json` module (or `simplejson` prior to Python 2.6).

You'd only need to remember two functions: json.dumps and json.loads.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Answer (score 7):

JSON is definitely the way to go. It has a very small overhead and is capable of storing almost any kind of data. I am not a python expert, but i am sure that there is some kind of en/decoder available.

Comment: I like JSON too, but it really doesn't have "small" overhead unless you're comparing to something a lot worse (XML).  For example, in an array of objects of the same type, the object field names are repeated in each one. Of course it's possible to re-work the data structure to factor out the field names, but it'd be nice to have an encoding format that would do it automatically.

Comment: +1 on JSON. simplejson is a python package that can help you doing that.

Comment: @Pointy: Thats right, but i do not know of a format that has a smaller overhead than JSON. At least no native one.

Comment: Ok, i wouldnt say json has a small over head. And whats the best JSON converter in javascript because for some reason javascript cant natively convert string to JSON array.

Comment: Google Protocol Buffers would be one example of a format with significantly lower overhead, as would any binary format. That's not to say there's anything wrong with JSON, which seems perfectly adequate for this.

Comment: @kizzie33: JSON is a native JavaScript notation (JSON means _"JavaScript Object Notation"_). You can simply output the generated JSON in the JavaScript code like this: `var data = YOUR_GENERATED_JSON_GOES_HERE;`. I recommend FireBug's `console.log(data)` command to inspect the resulting object.

Comment: no if i do a = "{'a':1,'b':2}";, a is now a string containing {'a':1,'b':2} not an array. I know what JSON is but javascript has no way to export and import it

Comment: @kizzle33: You can use the JSON2 library at http://json.org/json2.js. On modern browsers, it will use a native JSON parser.

Comment: @kizzie33: I did not mean to output `"{'a':1,'b':2}"` but `{'a':1,'b':2}`. This is what JavaScript understands natively.